# Create document with json array in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a cross of several tables in a pyspark view.

[image]

I need to create the following structure

```js
{
  "id" :1, 
  "colors": [
    {
      "color" :"blue"
    },
     {
      "color" :"yellow"
    }
    ],
    "sizes" :[
      
    {
      "size" :"M"
    },
     {
      "size" :"P"
    }
    ],
  "hash" :123
  
}
```

Comment: Please no images of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this spark-sql solution:

Input:

```
val df = spark.sql("""
select 1 id, 'blue' color, 'M' size, 'abc' store, 123 hash union all
select 1, 'yellow','P','abc', 123 union all 
select 2, 'blue', 'M', 'cdf', 232 
""")
df.show(false)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

+---+------+----+-----+----+
|id |color |size|store|hash|
+---+------+----+-----+----+
|1  |blue  |M   |abc  |123 |
|1  |yellow|P   |abc  |123 |
|2  |blue  |M   |cdf  |232 |
+---+------+----+-----+----+
```

Output:

```
spark.sql("""
with t1 ( select id, hash, collect_list(struct(color)) colors, collect_list(struct(size)) sizes  from df group by id,hash )
  select to_json(struct(id,colors,sizes,hash)) res   from t1
""").show(false)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|res                                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"id":2,"colors":[{"color":"blue"}],"sizes":[{"size":"M"}],"hash":232}                                |
|{"id":1,"colors":[{"color":"blue"},{"color":"yellow"}],"sizes":[{"size":"M"},{"size":"P"}],"hash":123}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Beautiful! Very elegant!

Comment: @stack0114106  Thank you for the answer . I tried to create an alias collect_list(struct(color).alias('color_RGB')) it didn't work. Would there be any way to rename the field?

Comment: try  ````collect_list(named_struct("color_RGB",color)) colors````

Comment: @stack0114106
In that same document I came across this structure, would there be another solution to solve this part?   "ids": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "caracterist": {
                "color": "blue",
                "store": "abc"               
            },
            "size": {
                "name: 'M"}],